# Strange image icon appeared in question post

Tags: discussion, questions

Strange image icon appeared on question even if there was no image there in first place..

Take a look that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548417/searchview-customization-in-android)..

Below is the image of the post..

[image]..

This scene was observed in my Chrome Browser..but when I cross checked in Mozilla Firefox browser the was no prob at all..

***Browser details..***

**Browser**: Google Chrome.(Issue observed)
**Version** 27.0.1453.116 m

**Browser**: Mozilla Firefox.(No issue here)
**Version** 23.0

Please take a look at this...

Comment: There is an image in that post.  I'm not sure why you think there isn't.

Comment: @cadrell0 My main question was **Why this appeared only in chrome and not in Firefox**

Comment: Because Chrome and Firefox are different browsers.

Comment: When I "Right click -> Open image in new tab", I see a page with "Error (403)" message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone posted an image on dropbox and used that as the image source in their post.

This image was later deleted from dropbox (I am guessing) - one way or another, it is no longer at that URL.

Stack Exchange has no control over third party content hosting - this is one reason we are using a Stack Exchange specific imgur domain that gives us some control and ensuring that images do not break like this. If you are the image rights holder, upload it, don't link it...

Comment: Hmm, that was my initial guess, BUT, how come this appeared only on chrome and no indication in firefox browser

Comment: @CRUSADER - caching?

Comment: @CRUSADER Chrome and Firefox handle missing images differently. Chrome usually displays a "missing image" glyph like this, while Firefox typically displays the alt text. [See this page for example](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremy/Fw5h9/).

Comment: @Oded Your last para clears all doubts.. Thanks for noticing and answering..